# changing a columns name that starts with a numeric value

Tags: postgresql

I am attempting to change a column name but there is an issue because my original column name has a number.

Here is what my table columns looks like

```
name price small medium large xl 2xl 3xl
```

When i do the following

```
ALTER TABLE tableName 
RENAME small TO abc;
```

It executes well.

However when i do the following

```
ALTER TABLE tableName 
RENAME 2xl TO xxl;
```

I get error saying `syntax error at or near "2"`

Does this mean i can never change this column's name because it starts with a numeric value?

Comment: Put the column name in double quotes.  `alter table tableName rename "2xl" to xxl;`

Comment: That did it @Hambone please post your answer so i can accept it so others may benefit too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time a column name begins with a non-alpha character, or contains special characters (spaces, etc) or is a keyword like "from," (but don't do that), you have to put the column name in quotes:

```
alter table tableName rename "2xl" to xxl;
```

As an aside, it's generally advisable to avoid object names that require double quotes.  It's just more work in everything else.  It's not wrong precisely speaking, just more work.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the identifier with the special characters in double quotes.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename 
            RENAME "2xl" TO xxl;
```